# Convert / Change Div element with Form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I'm using panelbar, hence form tag is disturbing it's open/close animation

I found that form tag is creating issue, so I want div tag to convert to form tag when I click submit button.

Eg:

```
<div class="myForm">
<div id="detail">
    Name: <input type="text" name="text_name" value="Some text here to edit"/>
</div>
<div id="income">
    Income: <input type="text" name="text_income" value="your income"/>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Convert to:

```
<form name="input" id="" action="html_form_action.php" method="post">
<div id="detail">
    Name: <input type="text" name="text_name" value="Some text here to edit"/>
</div>
<div id="income">
    Income: <input type="text" name="text_income" value="your income"/>
</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So all I want is change the div with class ".myForm" to Form element
and closing div with closing form tag.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: u can add form elements before the div....

Answer (score 6):

Use Javascript + jQuery:

```
$('.myForm').children().unwrap().wrapAll("<form name='input' id='' action='html_form_action.php' method='post'></form>");
```

This removes the wrapping div ".myForm" with the `unwrap` method. Then wraps it's children with the `wrapAll` method.

Comment: Unsure why this has been downvoted. It does exactly what the OP wants. Rival answerer?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can done this work simply using Jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('form').html($('.myForm').html());
});
```

But if you want to do this, this is not correct because you use assign `id` of some element. So after append whole HTML into `<form>` you should remove `.myForm`.

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/jH65L/)

For remove div `with class .myForm` after append `innerhtml` into form, you can simply use `.remove`.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
       $('form').html($('.myForm').html());
       $('.myForm').remove();
    });
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/jH65L/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you do like html5, you can check out html5 "form Attribute", which allows you to use the form elements wherever you like, and you don't need to wrap the contents inside form tags.

Check this out

```
<form name="input" id="myform" action="html_form_action.php" method="post"></form>

<div class="myForm">
    <div id="detail">
       Name: <input type="text" name="text_name" value="Some text here to edit" form="myform" />
    </div>
    <div id="income">
       Income: <input type="text" name="text_income" value="your income" form="myform" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" form="myform" />
</div>
```